# change icon of file in project view tool window

Tags: intellij-idea, icons, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin that gives the ability to version control and other stuff, for viewing the files added to my vcs I need to show them with a different overlay icon. Using the api how to change file/folder icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `com.intellij.ide.FileIconProvider` interface and register your implementation using the `<fileIconProvider>` extension point.